# Null Error with Flutter Bluetooth Printer

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this function that should print a receipt with bluetooth printer. It should print some text and some files (screenshot Image and logo File). I am getting an error for some reason, here it is:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'readAsBytes' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 2806): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 2806): Tried calling: readAsBytes()
```

It says that readAsBytes was called on null, but I don't think it is, check the code below:

```
  class Print extends StatefulWidget {
 
  final File screenshot;
  Print({this.screenshot});

Future<Ticket> _ticket(PaperSize paper) async {
    final ticket = Ticket(paper);
    final Uint8List bytes = await widget.screenshot.readAsBytes();
    final Image image = decodeImage(bytes);
    ticket.image(image);}
```

That is the print screen, and the function that sends that screenshot to this screen is this one:

```
_screenshot() {
screenshotController.capture(pixelRatio: 1.5).then((File image) {
  //Capture Done
  setState(() {
    _screenshot = image;
  });
  print('Successful Screenshot => $_screenshot');
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Print(
                screenshot: _screenshot,
                
              )));
  print(_screenshot.path);
  //print('$_screenshot deleted');
}).catchError((onError) {
  print(onError);
});
```

}

I am using the esc_pos_bluetooth: ^0.2.8 library. Let me know if you guys know what this error is and how it could be solved and let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setstate is trying to rebuild the widget. Try without using setstate.

Instead, try this:

```
_screenshot() {
screenshotController.capture(pixelRatio: 1.5).then((File image) {
  //Capture Done

    _screenshot = image;

  print('Successful Screenshot => $_screenshot');
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Print(
                screenshot: _screenshot,
                
              )));
  print(_screenshot.path);
  //print('$_screenshot deleted');
}).catchError((onError) {
  print(onError);
});
```

Comment: I'll get on it asap and let you know how it turned out!

Comment: Edit: Tried to do it like that, still getting same issue. The problem comes when I try to click on a bluetooth device.

Comment: Seems to have done the trick, I believe it should work now, albeit I haven't been able to test it out with the bluetooth printer, but emulator isn't giving me any errors.

Comment: Great! Just a tip: try to use FutureBuilder for such task, cause it makes life easy for handling any errors in future functions.